# Indexing URL pointing to pdf using TIKA in SOLR

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I have a requirement where the incoming update request has a metadata like "link":"htp://example.pdf" (along with some other metadata) and i have to parse the PDF document and indexed it in another field like "link_value":"PDF extracted contents". Is this possible in SOLR using tika?

NOTE: I cannot use Data import handler since the incoming request is not from a single source and is done via external source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly:

- you are getting some /update call to add some doc
- the doc contains a 'link' field, which you want to retrieve, extract text with Tika, and index into another field

Yes you can do this in Solr, but you need to do some work:

1. set up an UpdateRequestProcessor, you could start off [TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory.html) as it uses Tika too and maybe you can reuse some stuff
2. you wire your URP so it is used by the /update handler
3. that URP will kick in every time a doc is added
4. in the URP code, you: retrieve the pdf, programatically extract the text with Tika, and add it to the target field

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Is there a way to do it using configuration alone or we can handle it only programatically?

Comment: only programmatically, I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

You can [map content to a specific field and supply specific field values](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika#UploadingDatawithSolrCellusingApacheTika-InputParameters) when you're using the `ExtractingRequestHandler` (if you're using Tika yourself, you'll include the content as a regular document field).

To map the content to a different field, use `fmap`:  `fmap.content=link_value`, and to include a literal value (i.e. the URL of the document you're indexing), use `literal`: `literal.link=http://example.com/test.pdf` (apply URL escaping as necessary).